# NSView Drop Shadow Using setShadow:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, nsview, dropshadow

I'm attempting to make a drop shadow for a custom `NSView` subclass.

So far, I've managed:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        NSShadow *dropShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
        [dropShadow setShadowColor: [NSColor redColor]];

        [self setWantsLayer: YES];
        [self setShadow: dropShadow];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor blueColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

    [super drawRect: dirtyRect];
}
```

which only renders a blue square (i.e. no shadow).

Am I setting up the drop shadow in the right place?
Am I meeting all of the necessary requirements for the use of `setShadow:`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A few notes before answering the question:

- You don't need to call `super`'s implementation of `drawRect:` on a vanilla `NSView`. The default implementation does nothing.
- You should be using `[self bounds]` as the fill rectangle, not `dirtyRect`. The `dirtyRect` parameter is used to indicate the part of the view that needs drawing and is used for drawing optimisation only.
- You are leaking the `dropShadow` object. You should either call `autorelease` on it after creation or call `release` on it after calling `setShadow:`.

The reason that the shadow isn't displaying are twofold. Firstly, in order for layer-backed views to display a shadow, the view's superview must also be layer-backed.

Secondly, you're setting the shadow's color but not its other parameters:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        NSShadow *dropShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
        [dropShadow setShadowColor:[NSColor redColor]];
        [dropShadow setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(0, -10.0)];
        [dropShadow setShadowBlurRadius:10.0];

        [self setWantsLayer: YES];
        [self setShadow: dropShadow];

        [dropShadow release];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: The "leak" of the dropShadow is only a "leak" if you do not compile the file of pcperini's method with ARC (Automatic Reference Counting).  ARC is in common use at this point, and invoking release or autorelease will cause a compile error when ARC is enabled.